# Garbage/random characters displayed after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, cloudflare

I'm struggling with an issue that only some users of an ASP.NET 4.0 website are seeing.  Users are occasionally seeing this after performing a postback:

[image: character output]

I've not been able to replicate it myself but its now occurred on up-to-date versions of Firefox and Chrome.  Its a standard setup site i.e. in IIS it was created as a new site, changed the .NET version and added bindings.  There has been no further modification to the IIS setup and its been running for a number of years

The site does also run behind Cloudflare which is only used for SSL and auto-minification of CSS and HTML

The only thing I can think would be in relation to compression but i've never changed any settings with this and its not a consistent issue seen with all users even when using the same version of Chrome/Firefow (i.e. the latest version)

Comment: do you suspect that its part of your content which must be shown to the user?

Comment: The users in question are saying they get to the login page, can see that ok, enter credentials and upon pressing the login button and it triggering a post back they get presented with that garbage.  So they do see an initial page

Comment: What is the url of the garbage page? Can you show us the View Source of the garbage page? Do you see that behaviour if you disable javascript on your own browser?

Comment: have you included `<meta charset="UTF-8">` at header?

Comment: If you can replicate it, try browsing the site with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) - you'll need to install fiddler root certs to allow it to proxy SSL content.  This may just identify what the cause of the issue is, or at the very least give you a full two-way history of the browser communication.  It should also warn you if there are SSL issues.  That's where I would start, but as with most debugging, it rests largely on being able to reliably reproduce it.

Comment: It would be helpful to also see the code that generates this page.